# How to check if an element already exists then create another one of it after user input

Tags: javascript, createelement

I am creating a To-Do-List application. After user inputs something like"wash laundry", a ul appears to show it's on the to-do list. But the button doesn't work again when you click it the second time. How do I make sure the user can make another entry that will create a  new ul after clicking the button again like first time.

```
//this shows the ul
document.getElementById("add").addEventListener("click", function() {

  var exist = document.getElementById("todo").style.display = "block";
  document.getElementById("item").value = "";  //this is the input for entry
 }
//Here I want to create another one after user input
 if(exist=true) {
  document.createElement("ul") or just something like console.log("Found!");
    }
  //i get the error "exist" is not defined
```

Comment: You have a typo: `exist=true` is setting the value, not comparing it.

Comment: Please share a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Answer (score 0):

You are using the `exist` variable out of it's scope. Try removing the `var`. Like this:

`exist = document.getElementById("todo").style.display = "block";`

Also, in you IF statement you should always put `==` or `===`, but never `=`. This will cause the variable to be assigned, not compared.